# PHP version missing from local site PHP manager

Tags: php, .net, iis

I installed PHP with Microsoft web platform installer. It's showing up in the IIS php manager.[Server level php manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ3VU.png)

When I try to load the site, I get "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
 scriptProcessor could not be found in  application configuration".
Then I checked the site's PHP manager, the PHP version is missing.[Site level php manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsFCz.png)

When I try to manually add the PHP, I get "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object". [Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHJsv.png)

Comment: You posted too little about your web site, so there is no way to know why server level settings are gone. You must have configured something in `web.config` without fully understanding what it does. BTW, try your best to migrate to PHP on Linux, as PHP on Windows is losing support from Microsoft.

Comment: Besides, just noticed that you installed the so called 1.5 release from someone, which is known to have tons of issues. You should uninstall it and then use 2.x release https://github.com/phpmanager/phpmanager/releases